# heap size is too large while querying data from 6 objects and adding it to the single list

Tags: heap, heapsizelimit

I am querying from six objects and adding it to single sobject list. each object is having around 4000 records and 40 fields in each object. so total records will 24000 and all those records i keeping inside single list. while running the code i am getting error as heap size is too large. 
note in each query i am querying around 40 fields .

similar code snippet

```
List<sObject> sobjectlist = new List<sObject>();
for(object1__c obj1 : [select id,name from object1__c])
{
sobjectlist.add((sobject)obj1);
}
for(object2__c obj2 : [select id,name from object2__c])
{
sobjectlist.add((sobject)obj2);
}
for(object3__c obj3 : [select id,name from object3__c])
{
sobjectlist.add((sobject)obj3);
}
for(object4__c obj4 : [select id,name from object4__c])
{
sobjectlist.add((sobject)obj4);
}
for(object5__c obj5 : [select id,name from object5__c])
{
sobjectlist.add((sobject)obj5);
}
for(object6__c obj6 : [select id,name from object6__c])
{
sobjectlist.add((sobject)obj6);
}
```

Comment: That kind of code takes around 1.5M out of the 6M of heapsize, I guess you are doing something more than what you say in your post.

Have you considered moving the logic to a Batch?

Comment: i have checked for each query it is utilizing more than 1m so all together it is coming around 7.5m . note that for each object i am having around 40 fields.

Comment: try to move that logic in the batch so the heap size will be increased to 12M for asynchronous transaction.

Comment: this logic i am using in my custom controller.

Comment: If you don't plan to do DMLs, you could put in the apex:page `readOnly="true"`

Comment: I am using DMLs